# How to starve internet speed from Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to experiment with networking in my Java application. For starters, I would like to test how much networking power can I use before a website begins loading slowly.

Is there a reasonable way to deliberately consume so many networking resources that it affects my browsing experience?

As for my attempts, I tried to create several threads, each trying to download some website (like this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html), but this doesn't do anything to my internet speed (I guess that the amount of threads is just too little).

Comment: google for "java network throtting"

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, thanks, I have searched it now. However, the results seem to be about limiting the download/upload speed of something in Java - but what I want is to do *something* in my Java app to cause the entire computer to slowdown network-wise.

Comment: that makes no sense. Why not set your server to throttle outbound bandwidth instead? What are you actually trying to test

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, Given a computer, let's say that it downloads something/anything at 10MB per second. I wanted to know if there is a way, in a Java program, to starve the computer to the point that it can't download at 10MB per second, but rather, at a much lower speed. No, there is no practical use to this - but this is what I wanted to know: how to starve a computer's internet speed from Java.

Comment: that's not an answer. That says what effect you want, not what you want to find out that requires you achieve that effect. Why do you need to drop the network rate of the computer? What are you doing that requires system level network throttling?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: I want to make an application that alerts me when the download/upload speed of my computer is abnormal, so first I want to reproduce such abnormality. Since I am into Java, I'd rather do it all in Java - but if it isn't possible, I'm fine with a different language.

Comment: see, that is a *completely* different thing than what you were asking about. What you want is a java library for monitoring your network device's bandwidth vs. throughput.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: Such library would be a solution to the program I want to make, but I still need a way to reproduce the abnormality consistently, so I made this question asking how to.

Comment: Not related to Java, but if you want to overload your connection just install a Torrent client and download a few Linux ISOs in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you download some big files instead of just HTML web sites. Try different files from different sites so it does not limit your download by your IP or session.

Also if you really want to slow down your navigation experience you need to consume your **upload** as well, not only your download link. Try uploading something at max speed, it will greatly affect your navigation.

You can make some tests for comparison with [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/).